# Debugging Angular 2 application running in lite-server in WebStorm

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, webstorm

I have installed Chrome extension "JetBrains IDE Support" and it is running under port 63341.

My `package.json` script looks like this:

```
"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

However, when I run "debug run" in WebStorm, I'm getting a

> Connection refused: connect

after a while.

I tried adding `-node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION%` to the command, but it doesn't help.

What confuses me is that the "Debugger" tab in WebStorm shows that it's trying to connect to some port on localhost that is always different from 63342 and that disappears right when the error message pops up.

Comment: sorry, what would you like to debug? tsc? Or the lite server? What's the reason for running this script in debugger?

Comment: I would like to debug my angular2 app running on the lite webserver.

Comment: there is no need to debug npm script then. See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to debug Angular2 application hosted on lite server, you need creating `JavaScript Debug` run configuration, specify the lite server URL (`http://localhost:3000` or whatever it looks like) as `URL` there, and press Debug. Of course, you need to start the server first by running your `npm start` script. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I now created a `JavaScript Debug Configuration`, ran my `run` script and the debug configuration, so my app starts in a new chrome tab with a yellow notifaction on top that confirms that "Jetbrains IDE Support" is debugging this browser", but somehow no breakpoints are triggered. any idea? I set some breakpoints both in typescript aswell as in the dist/js files and confirmed that the source maps are created.

Comment: I'm fighting with the exact same problem (using the most recent Webstorm 2016.3.1)

Comment: @camden_kid: remote URL mappings are likely required; also, you have to refresh browser page to get breakpoints in code executed on page loading hit. If you need advise on setting up the mappings, please create support tickets

Comment: if you are using angular-cli with webpack, please check this thread (last posts there) - you may find it helpful: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207283009-debug-angular-cli-project?page=1#community_comment_204514050

Comment: I somehow messed up the creation of the source map files.